# How to show Numbers in Vaadin Text- or NumberFields formatted in Currency Style?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I just want an editable field show Number as A Currency like

```
1.444.444,90
```

I already checked [NumeralFieldFormatter](https://github.com/johanneshayry/textfieldformatter/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/textfieldformatter/NumeralFieldFormatter.java) but when i use it with Constructor or Builder. It doesn't matter it always gives me something like 20000.0

```
NumeralFieldFormatter currencyOne = new NumeralFieldFormatter.Builder()
                .decimalMark(",")
                .decimalScale(2)
                .delimiter(".")
                .thousandsGroupStyle(NumeralFieldFormatter.ThousandsGroupStyle.THOUSAND)
                .build();
currencyOne.extend(textfield);
```

What do I do wrong or is there a better possibility in vaadin? How can such a big Framework have nothing built in for Currencies or do I simply not find it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you had a look at NumberField? https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/number-field

Comment: Yes, of course but how can i get the thousand seperators in BigDecimal? The Example shown there is 
**948205817.472950487**
but I need 

***948.205.817,47***

Comment: Oh yes you are right! Are you using a Binder? There you can format and parse it in the Converter

Comment: No I don't. perhaps you can specify the Binder you mean? and what converter?

Comment: I mean this: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/components-binder

Comment: and what exactly is the solution for my problem there?

Comment: is there a currency binder?#

Comment: No you don't need a currency binder. You need a converter that formats the currency.

Comment: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/components-binder-validation/#implementing-the-converter-interface

Comment: Ok, but i don't want people to press the ** . ** -Key to enter a number. If you enter 
**123456789,99** it should automatically print out
**123.456.789,99**

Comment: They don't have to. It will be formatted after the user entered the number

Comment: I really don't get it. Could you please give an Example for using this with a numberField? PLease!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Binder with a converter:

```
public class HelloWorldView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final DecimalFormat decimalFormate = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.00");

    public HelloWorldView() {
        Binder<Person> binder = new Binder<>(Person.class);

        TextField name = new TextField("Name");
        binder.forField(name)
                .bind("name");

        TextField salary = new TextField("Salary");
        binder.forField(salary)
                .withConverter(new Converter<String, BigDecimal>() {
                    @Override
                    public Result<BigDecimal> convertToModel(String value, ValueContext context) {
                        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
                            return Result.ok(new BigDecimal(0));
                        } else {
                            return Result.ok(new BigDecimal(value));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String convertToPresentation(BigDecimal value, ValueContext context) {
                        if (value == null) {
                            return "";
                        } else {
                            return decimalFormate.format(value);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .bind("salary");

        binder.setBean(new Person());

        add(name, salary);
    }
```

Please find the whole example here:
https://github.com/simasch/vaadin-formatting

Comment: but it says
***ILLEGALARGUMENTEXCEPTION***
```
Multiple decimal separators in pattern "###.###.###,00"
```

Comment: You must use the separators as in my code! They will be changed based on the Locale! https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html